# How to modify post-build event command in order to copy only exact dll(s) instead of copy the whole folder?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, build, project

I am facing an issue that even though setting up copy-local to false for .dlls; On nuget package update it's automatically gets set to true and which causing the issue in a build process.

Can anyone please suggest is there any way to configure in post-build event to copy only required dlls instead of copy the whole folder?

Any help appreciated?

Comment: I want to copy only class library name.dll and not other supporting.dlls as supporting .dlls are already part of the common project.

Comment: write a powershell script and only copy the ones with your company's digital signature

Comment: Do you want the copy destination to be the build output folder or another folder?

Comment: Yes I want to copy build output but only specific dlls not all supporting ones

Comment: Steve - Any sample/Reference to write powershell script?